# Getting characters from random number generator in Java

Tags: java, random, permutation

I am supposed to create a program that calls a method that generates permutations of the numbers 1 to 10.  Basically, I'm supposed to fill an array with random numbers between 1-10 that never gets a repeat number, and gets different results every time I call the method.  I used the Random() class but for some reason it is generating symbols, characters, and numbers.  Here is my program:

```
import java.util.*;

 public class perms
   {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     int[] myPermutation;
     myPermutation = generatePermutation1To10();
     System.out.println(myPermutation);
    }

    private static int[] generatePermutation1To10() {
       Random rng = new Random();
       int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
       int[] finalNums = new int[nums.length];

       for (int k=0;k<finalNums.length; ++k)
       {
           int rnIdx = rng.nextInt(nums.length-k);
           finalNums[k] = nums[rnIdx];
           nums[rnIdx] = nums[nums.length-k-1];
       }
       return finalNums;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those characters aren't your random characters instead of random integers.  That is the default output of [the `toString()` method in `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), which arrays (which are objects too) don't override.

> [T]his method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

You probably saw something like this:

```
[I@68111f9b
```

The `[I` is Java's code for array (`[`) of `int` (`I`), and the `68111f9b` is the hexadecimal output of the hash code for the array.

Try

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myPermutation));
```

Comment: Worth adding to this answer that what you WERE printing out was a memory location. That's why it looked like random numbers and characters.

Comment: Worked!  Thanks a lot!  I had no clue it did that.

Comment: @John it's not a memory location

Comment: It's actually the object's hashCode in hexadecimal with a type prefix.

Comment: @Cruncher Oops. You're both right. It's `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you're seeing the internal representation of the array.  Use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29) to print out your array:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myPermutation));
```